# Read local xml files and return as JSON/XML via web service

Tags: c#, web-services

We have a number of XML files that we currently FTP up to various locations that we would like to replace with one Web Service.

For example say we have the xml files that represent things in our universe e.g.: stars.xml, planets.xml, galaxies.xml

These XML files may be of various complexities from simple to complex, but all will be well formed syntax.

We would like to be able to place these files xml files to a central location and then return the XML/JSON by calling for example MY.API/1/stars or MY.API/1/planets etc

These xml files may be updated hourly and we would want to display the updated data.

Is this solution reasonable and could you provided any architectural tips?

Comment: This is a very broad question and it's unclear what exactly you're asking for. What have you tried? What are you considering doing and why are you worried doing that is "wrong"?

Comment: I know, it is more of an architectural and if it is a reasonable approach. I haven't built a service in some time

Comment: It's hard to really talk about architectural aspects at this point without more to go on. Currently you've only listed a few requirements but no actual solution description. If all you want is to serve a list of XML files, then an FTP server is probably way easier to maintain, or buy some server space at some provider, or put it in a gist or repository at GitHub.